# Google App Engine Start program Failed

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have a very basic NodeJS application hosted on Google App Engine that executes an async function on 15 second intervals. The deployment is successful and the app starts and runs fine, but stops after about 30 minutes with the following error logs. This runs fine locally, though.

> Quitting on terminated signal
>
> Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated

I have used App Engine before with no issues, so I'm not sure why this is happening. I used https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/typescript as a reference (and cloned this project and deployed) and am still not able to resolve this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your app's logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added the logs regarding the issue in the description above. I made a slight change and this is the updated log: "[start] 2021/08/29 23:18:34.379768 Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart(): [aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/valid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:119295 aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/invalid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:119363]"

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's worth noting I am not even trying to host a server. It is a twitter bot node app, so there is no reason to access it from the browser.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so I just pulled Google's Hello World example and tried deploying without any changes and got the same thing. It looks like the application actually isn't killed (can still access the express.js endpoint Google provides by deafault), just the terminal and any processes running there (my setTimeout).